# Custom Mapping in Nhibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

Im just trying out nHibernate and I want to use a generic class to map several tables. How can I achieve something like this by using nHibernate with sql aggregation? Also, by mapping several aggregated tables to a generic object, would it mean that I wouldn't have to specify the table name in the xml map? Is this possible in nHibernate and, if not, is there any other way to do this without creating a view in the db?

I am currently working on a reporting project.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your question, [this](http://ayende.com/blog/2327/multi-table-entities-in-nhibernate) is what you're looking for

> Name and sex are defined in the Person table, but everything else is defined on the Address table, we map it like this:

```
<class name="Person">
   <id name="Id" column="person_id" unsaved-value="0">
       <generator class="native"/>
   </id>

   <property name="Name"/>
   <property name="Sex"/>

   <join table="address">
          <key column="address_id"/>
          <property name="Address"/>
          <property name="Zip"/>
          <property name="Country"/>
          <property name="HomePhone"/>
          <property name="BusinessPhone"/>
   </join>
</class>
```